# a foreign key constraint fails error

Tags: php, mysql

i get the following errors when trying to update the join table:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id
Notice: Undefined variable: course_id

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`school-project`.`students_courses`, CONSTRAINT `fk_courses` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)0 Row inserted.
```

the 3 tables are:

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Comments    Extra
1   id Primary Index    int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   student_id Index    int(11)         No  None        
3   course_id Index int(11)         Yes NULL    


#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Comments    Extra
1   idPrimaryIndex  int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   name    varchar(255)    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
3   phone   varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
4   email   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
5   image   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    

#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Comments    Extra

1   idPrimaryIndex  int(11)         No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   nameIndex   varchar(20) latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
3   descr   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
4   image   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

the code:

```
function joinTable() {
    global $connection;
    $join_table_sql = "INSERT INTO students_courses (student_id, course_id)
VALUES ('$id', '$course_id')";
    if ($connection->query($join_table_sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $join_table_sql . "<br>" . $connection->error;
    }
}
```

what am i missing? why do i get those errors??       .

Comment: what values are in $id and $course_id? 
these should be exsisting student_id and course_id from the corresponding tables

Comment: Well for starters, there are no variables named $id and $course_id available in your function ... looks like you should go read up on variable scope in PHP.

Comment: ah yes: setting the error_reporting to E_ALL and display_errors ON should warn you (in your dev environment) for missing vars

Answer (score 1):

How do you get `$id`and `$course_id` ?

The first error is in the `PHP Notice` also you don't insert empty values in `sql`

*This should be a comment, but i don't have a reputation... :(

Comment: I didn't see that part in the post. Indeed it is best to solve problem from the top down. There's 2 variables missing is the first problem

solve that, and then see if there are still other problems, or they may disappear when the vars are present.